Vlookup / Xlookup / Index & Match... Which one and
This is Sheet1 with Orders
Notice that there is the same Ref ID DEF456 for different Orders !



Ref ID
Order Number




ABC123
ORD001


DEF456
ORD002


GHI789
ORD003


DEF456
ORD004


DEF456
ORD005



In Sheet2



Ref ID
Order Number
Status




ABC123
ORD001
success


DEF456
ORD002
success


GHI789
ORD003
fail


DEF456
ORD004
success


DEF456
ORD005
fail



I need to return the Status for each order.
The problem is i can't lookup a Column if the Ref ID & Order number are separated
I tried to combine the Column1 & Column2 but the problem is with the rang.
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,B2),Sheet2!,3,0)
=VLOOKUP(JOIN("",A2,b2),Sheet2!,3,0)
=XLOOKUP(AND(CONCATENATE(A2,B2),Sheet2!A2:A=A2:A,Sheet2!B2:B=B2:B),Sheet2!C2:C)
=INDEX(Sheet2!A2:C,MATCH(JOIN("",A2,B2),AND({Sheet2!A2:A}=A2,{Sheet2!B2:B}=B2),0),MATCH(JOIN("",A2,B2),Sheet2!1:1,0))

The vlookup() help page shows how to search with multiple criteria. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet with realistic-looking data. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.


You may try this single formula in your sheet1 Cell_C2:
=arrayformula(vlookup(A2:A&B2:B,{Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C},2,))



I also found this formula it's almost the same to @rockinfreakshow's answer
=ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP(A2&B2,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,"Not Found",0,1))

here's the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15o-SxjJF-I3DErwxGHetY7yzo19fGjoDi77lIswB7sk/edit?usp=sharing
